Addition of regression coefficients in Linear Probability Models?
I'm reading this paper
Sangyoon Park (2018) Coeducation, academic performance, and subject choice: evidence from quasi-random classroom assignments, Education Economics, 26:6, 574-592, DOI: 10.1080/09645292.2018.1515310
My question is about the interpretation of linear probability models coefficients:

Next, to test whether coeducational learning affects students’ decisions on subject choices, I
regress students’ enrollment decisions on each advanced subject on the coeducation classroom indi-
cator variable. As control variables, I include each student’s test scores on math and science/arts sub-
jects (depending on the enrolled curriculum) from the previous grade and add cohort fixed effects.
This methodology results in the following linear specification for each science/arts subject:
Enrollic = a + bCoedic + dGirlic + gCoed × Girlic + Xic + hc + eic, (3)
where Enrollic is an indicator variable equal to one if student i in cohort c enrolls in a specific subject,
for instance, Physics. To detect differences in subject choice behaviors across a classroom’s gender
type, the parameters of interest are β for boys and b + g for girls. Specifically, if b + g is positive,
this would indicate that girls in coeducation classrooms are more likely to enroll in that particular
subject relative to girls in single-sex classrooms.


The third row presents estimates for the interaction term between coeducation and the student being a female. To check for the effect of coeducation on girls’ science course enrollment decisions, in the table, I provide the sum of the coefficients on Coed (β) and Coed × Girl (γ). I find that a girl in a
coeducation classroom is, on average, 15 percentage points more likely to learn Physics than a girl in
a single-sex classroom. The estimate is statistically significant at the 10 % level and represents a
remarkable jump of 71.4% (= 15/21 ∗ 100) in the tendency to choose to learn physics.

Can anyone explain about the addition of coefficients?

Do you specifically mean the if b + g is positive comment? $//$ I took a shot at formatting the quotes you posted. Please do feel free to roll it back if I did not do it correctly.

It sounds like you might want to research the meaning and interpretation of an interaction, especially of binary ("dummy") variables.  I believe Isabella Ghement thoroughly addressed such questions in an answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/471136/919, found by searching our site.  Am I correct, or are you trying to ask something different?

Thanks Dave. Just the idea of adding b + g. Why not adding also d?

Thanks, whuber! Very clear

This is a standard coding of binary predictors. We can forget all the other predictors in the model for a moments and just consider a single binary $X$ predictor representing gender; we'll say $X=0$ for boys and $X=1$ for girls. We can fit the following regression model:
$$
E[Y|X] = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X
$$
The predicted value of the outcome for boys is $E[Y | X = 0] = \beta_0$, and the predicted value of the outcome for girls is $E[Y | X = 1] = \beta_0 + \beta_1$. The difference between these two is $\beta_1$. To test whether the predicted value for boys differs from the predicted value for girls, we only need to test whether $\beta_1$ differs from 0.
The model in the paper include an interaction between gender and another predictor, "Coed", which seems to indicate whether a student is in a coed class. I'll denote this variable as $C$, where $C=0$ for non-coed and $C=1$ for Coed. We'll fit the model like the one used in the paper:
$$
E[Y|X,C] = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \beta_2 C + \beta_3 XC
$$
The paper is concerned with the effect of $C$ for each gender. We can rewrite this model as follows, simply grouping the terms:
$$
E[Y|X,C] = (\beta_0 + \beta_1 X) + (\beta_2 + \beta_3 X)C
$$
We can ask what the effect of $C$ is for boys and for girls by looking at the slope term (in the second set of parentheses) on $C$. For boys ($X=0$), the slope on $C$ is $\beta_2$, and for girls ($X=1$), the slope on $C$ is $\beta_2 + \beta_3$. The need to add the coefficients together comes straight from the definition of the model. This is not the only way to fit this model, but it is the most common. To test whether the slope of $C$ for boys differs from the slope on $C$ for girls, one only needs to test whether $\beta_3$ differs from 0.
